# How to stop a phone from ringing without rejecting the call?

Tags: calls, ringtone, missed-calls, silent-mode

Sometimes I don't want to take a call, but I don't want him to know that. So I left the phone be until it stops, so it would appear that I'm away from phone or something and I miss the call. Can I silence the ringing tone and the vibration while doing that?

**Info**: My phone is Galaxy S

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect this is very much device dependent, but on the HTC Desire HD, you can press the physical volume down button to silence the ringtone whilst allowing the call to continue.

Comment: My phone is Galaxy S. Edited that in the info. Will try this next time I get a call.

Comment: Can't verify this, but the following forum thread suggests that the volume key should work on the Galaxy S too. Have you given it a go? http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s/124007-mute-ringtone-alert-when-receiving-call.html

Comment: This volume-down trick works on my Droid 2 Global (Motorola) as well (running Android 2.2).

Comment: I've a Galaxy S, but the volume down trick does *not* work. I called my S a few times but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: @mark: For SGS, hold the button. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The HTC Desire allows you to flip the phone face down to silence that call. If that doesn't work with the Samsung then you can probably use Tasker to arrive at a similar result (put the phone into silent mode when it's face down).

Comment: Interesting idea!

Comment: There are a couple of apps out there that will do the same.

Comment: Side question: after having used this exact feature (called "silence incoming calls" on my phone), as of a few months ago, my phone only rings or vibrates once (shorter than a 1s), as if "silence incoming calls" kicked in, in spite of me not having touched the phone which is lying on its back, not upside down on the screen. Is this a bug, is there a workaround, is it a HW failure of some sort? P880 user, BTW. Would this make more sense as a separate question, rather than a comment?

Answer (score 5):

For Samsung Galaxy S, the way is to **hold** the volume down button. If you just press, nothing happens (or maybe you have to press it several times before it completely stops ringing, I don't know, but holding it makes it stop immediately)

Comment: Works also for Galaxy Ace. Maybe it would be a good idead to update the question with some devices that have been tested so far?

Answer (score 3):

For Samsung Galaxy S, you have press the power button to put your phone on silent when it rings

Comment: and if you keep the power button pressed, it stops all annoying noises :)

Answer (score -1):

Holding down lower volume button also works on LG stylo 2