# How do I silence incoming call and text message ringtone without hanging up in the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: audio, ringtone, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I have set up MP3 ringtones for both incoming calls and text messages on my new Galaxy Nexus, but I can't figure out how to silence them without hanging up (in the case of incoming calls) or without having to wait until the entire sound bite is over?  Any suggestions?  Does anyone know how to do that?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some possibilities here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4262/how-to-stop-a-phone-from-ringing-without-rejecting-the-call

Comment: Like the answers in the similar question Al linked to suggest, try pressing or holding various hardware buttons (Volume, for example.)

Comment: Doesn't pressing the volume button silence it?

Answer (score 5):

When the **Galaxy Nexus** is ringing...

Tap the power button on the right side of the screen.

The ringtone will stop and the screen will switch off. BUT the call has not been hung up.

You can even press the power button again to switch the screen back on and the ringtone is silent if the call is still waiting to be answered. The voice call will still be at the correct volume when you actually answer it.

Answer (score 3):

### Use volume-rocker

Click either up or down volume to silence your phone. This is the *user-manual-recommended* way. When you click it your screen stays on.

[Android user manual reference](http://support.google.com/android/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168447)

> ***Note:** this usually works with any phone, not just Androids. It used to work with old stupid-phones (antonym of smart-phones) as well.*

Answer (score 0):

A third option is to enable the setting so you can flip your phone face down when ringing to silence the phone.  Under Sound Settings > Phone Call Silence I believe.

Comment: Side question: after having used this exact feature (called "silence incoming calls" on my phone), as of a few months ago, my phone only rings or vibrates once (shorter than a 1s), as if "silence incoming calls" kicked in, in spite of me not having touched the phone which is lying on its back, not upside down on the screen. Is this a bug, is there a workaround, is it a HW failure of some sort? P880 user, BTW. Would this make more sense as a separate question, rather than a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Just press power key at the right side of device. It will become silent.